# "Inappropriate ioctl for device" when ripping CD with abcde on OSX

Tags: macos, compact-disc, ripping, abcde

I'm trying to use `abcde` (compiled from Macports) to rip an audio CD on OSX 10.8.5:

```
$ abcde
disk1 was already unmounted or it has a partitioning scheme so use "diskutil unmountDisk" instead
cd-discid: /dev/disk1: open: Permission denied
[ERROR] abcde: CD could not be read. Perhaps there's no CD in the drive?
```

Right, permission denied, retry with sudo.  But it still doesn't work:

```
$ sudo abcde
Password:
disk1 was already unmounted or it has a partitioning scheme so use "diskutil unmountDisk" instead
cd-discid: /dev/disk1: DKIOCCDREADDISCINFO: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[ERROR] abcde: CD could not be read. Perhaps there's no CD in the drive?
```

What is wrong?  How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `abcde` doesn't automatically detect which device corresponds to your CD drive.  If you look at the output of `mount`, you'll see that `disk1` is your hard disk and `disk2` is the CD drive, mounted on `/Volumes/Audio CD`.  You can specify the device explicitly with the `-d` option to `abcde`:

```
$ abcde -d /dev/disk2
```